# Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting

Tags: kernel

I had trouble opening the Software Centre in 12.04. I tried the troubleshooting given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure). After carrying out the instructions, I rebooted my computer only to find that I can't reach the login screen. Instead I get this error:

> Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting

Can someone please guide me through this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve that specific issue:

> Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting

Just use a live USB/DVD, mount your root system, edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` with root privileges and add the following line:

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

Reboot into your system and done.

Comment: I followed your instructions and found the line  already present \n # ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

Comment: @baalkikhaal the line was present without or with `#` at the start? Also, then you can reach the login screen? And that bug was fixed sometime ago. Could you update me, your system boots the same or not?

Comment: the character '#' was not present. and I am unable to reach the login screen. Actually, due to my oversight I installed Debian packages along with ubuntu packages. The effect of this reflected now during the bootup which shows some line having Debian/Linux Jessi/Sid ... I think the viable option would be to reinstall ubuntu and not repeat the mistake of mixing packages. thanks for the help provided.

Comment: Could you then add that as answer and accept it. Also edit your question and add the elements that helped you to identify the problem.

Comment: you mean your answer right?... i dont have enough karma to edit questions. the problem was related to apt. hence i posted this at [launchpad][1]. The suggestion was that the problem is serious and only a clean reinstall can make justice


  [1]: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/236738